# How to send push notification using c# from fcm to andriod, ios and web

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

Please help me with this error , Expected result to send push notification to web, I need guidance on  sending push notification to iPhone and android as well.

> Web Socket connection Error in connection establishment:
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>        Internal server error 500

Comment: I have used javascript and mvc controller

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some code using the respective iOS/google frameworks for push messages would be useful

Comment: I am unable to upload the sample code,
I have integrated the javascript code in my cshtml , from google console

Comment: I have written post method to save the token in the databse,

Comment: To send push notification i have written some method, Please help me with this

Comment: We cant help you when you don't show what you did attempt. cshtml are code files too (with markup). Otherwise the question will most likely be just closed since it provides to little information to help you

Comment: I am not getting how to upload , while upload it is always showing error, I have made every line add to dictionary then also it is showing error while uploading the code

Comment: Code is text, just edit your answer. People don't need the whole solution. Check [advanced help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see the markup language used in the editor and how to format it

Comment: Using this code I had integrated the javascript code  https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/26b635defe7088bc81185c750b04e625b15a4284/messaging/index.html#L198-L210